# How to retrieve current user session id from ci_sessions.?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to get current session id to use it in all pages. I want to pass session data in header. I can store my session in `ci_sessions` table. But how can I retreive current login username/sesson_id from `ci_sessions`.

here is my ci_sessions code.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

here is session setting code

```
if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $username =  $this->input->post('login_username');
                $password =  $this->input->post('login_password');


                // ip address
                //$ip_address= $this->user_activity->get_client_ip();

                 //Retrieving session data and other data
                    //$captcha_code=$_SESSION['captcha'];
                    //$user_agent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

                //call the model for auth
                $this->load->Model('Auth_model');
                if($this->Auth_model->login($username, $password)){


                    $data = array(
                            'client_username' => $username,
                            'is_logged_in' => true
                              );                    

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
                    //$this->session->set_flashdata('item', $datav['name']);

                }
                else{
                    echo'something went wrong';
                }
```

I am using pop dailog for login and signup so here is my ajax.

```
<script>
    $("input#login_btn").on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

            var x = document.forms["loginform"]["login_username"].value;
            var x1 = document.forms["loginform"]["login_password"].value;
            var y = document.getElementById('login-error');
            var z = document.getElementById('password-error');

            if (x == "") { y.style.display ='block'; }else{ y.style.display ='none'; }
            if (x1 == "") { z.style.display ='block'; }else{ z.style.display ='none'; } 

                var d = document.forms["loginform"]["login_username"].value;
                var d1 = document.forms["loginform"]["login_password"].value;       

        if(d != '' && d1 != ''){
                var url = $(this).attr('action');
                var method = $(this).attr('method');
                var data = $(this).serialize();

                $.ajax({
                   url:url,
                   type:method,
                   data:data
                }).done(function(data){
                   if(data !=='')
                    {

                        if(d !== '' && d1 != '' ){
                            //$("#login_fail").show('fast');
                            //$("#login_fail").effect( "shake" );
                            $('#loginform')[0].reset();
                            //var url = $('#current_loginurl').val();                   
                            //window.location.href=url;

                            var url = $('#current_loginurl').val();                 
                            window.location.href=url;

                        }                       
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var url = $('#current_loginurl').val();                 
                        window.location.href=url;
                        throw new Error('go');
                    } 
                });            

            $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
            var cl = $(this).attr('class');
            if(cl =='')
                {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `current session` from table like below.Get the records `order by` id in `descending` order having `limit` 1.

```
$this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
$this->db->limit(1);
$last_session = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->row_array();

print_r($last_session['data']);//prints current session data
```

**UPDATE**
But the easiest way to get current user `session id` is make use of `session` library.Like this..

```
$this->load->library('session');
$id = $this->session->userdata('id');//id is session variable that you set
echo $id;
```

Comment: where should I use it in controller ot view.?

Comment: in controller. dont forget to load database.

Comment: it gives me errror `**undefined index data**`

Comment: what is output on `print_r($last_session)`.

Comment: print_r($lase_session) give full row as resutl. But `print_r($lase_session['id'])` not working

Comment: can you post output of `print_r($last_session)`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => vb0lds642g5clbm5p46ao6s2rm89k2ch [ip_address] => ::1 [timestamp] => 1489848548 [data] => __ci_last_regenerate|i:1489848548; ) )  **this is output**

Comment: `$last_session = $this->db->get('ci_sessions')->row_array();` then `print_r($last_session['data']`.